# Tableau: Can Grand Totals have text (raw number) and rows have shapes?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have checkmarks representing matches in my cross-table/text table; however, for my grand total, I want to see the total count (i.e., count the number of checkmarks across the row). I currently just have a checkmark showing up. Can I differentiate marks in the regular columns with the grand total column? If so, how would I go about this? I've tried with messing with some of the settings, but I have not found the right one yet.

[image]

Comment: can you please share a sample scenario using Tableau Public

Answer (score 0):

Use the three calculated fields used in the comment thread, you need to map them to your fields, it will do the job